# How to override CakePHP Log() function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I need to override the default CakePHP Log() function so that it writes to the database instead of a file. I don't care whether or not this is a good idea, I simply want to know how I would go about firstly overriding what happens when I go `$this->Log("blah")` and secondly how I would reference the Log table element form within the app_controller or other class I am performing the override in.

Comment: You should consider to upgrade your CakePHP version. 2.x is much faster than 1.x. It has also a lot more possibilities, one of them is database logging

Comment: Let's just say I have to work with v1.3.

Comment: In that case, you should try that powerfull search engine. [first result](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-DatabaseLogger-Plugin)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I am not one of those people who add a plugin each time I want a new feature.

Comment: What is a "Log table element"? Are you talking about view elements or database tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a table in your database to store the logs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

In the `app/model` directory create a file called `log.php` and put this code in it:

```php
<?php

class Log extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Log';

    function write($type, $message) {
        $this->save(array(
            'Log' => array(
                'type' => $type,
                'message' => $message
            )
        ));
    }

}
```

That's the logging engine but it's also a model so you can customise it to use a different datasource or table. The only requirement is the write function that accepts those parameters.

Edit `app/config/bootstrap.php` and add this code at the end of the file:

```php
App::Import('Model','Log');

CakeLog::config('otherFile', array(
    'engine' => 'Log',
    'model' => 'Log',
));
```

You can now use the log with `$this->log($type, $message);` or `$this->log($message);` which defaults to the error type.

There is some info about creating [custom logging](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Logging.html#creating-and-configuring-log-streams) engines in the CakePHP manual.

Comment: Thanks. It's much more elegant than the solution I came up with in the end.